# When was the first tri-series for cricket held?

Tags: cricket, history, icc, tournaments

Tri-series is a series/tournament with three nations playing for the trophy.

- When was the first international tri-series for cricket matches held?
- Which nations participated in it and who was the winner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first tri-series **Test** tournament](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;filter=advanced;orderby=start;template=results;tournament_type=3;type=aggregate;view=series) was held in England in 1912, between [England, Australia, and South Africa](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/60296.html), and was won by England.

The [first tri-series **ODI** tournament](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;filter=advanced;orderby=start;template=results;tournament_type=3;type=aggregate;view=series) was held in Australia in 1979, between [Australia, West Indies, and England](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/60807.html), and was won by West Indies.

There appears to have [only been one **T20** tri-series](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=3;filter=advanced;orderby=start;template=results;tournament_type=3;type=aggregate;view=series) (all the other tournaments in the list had more than three teams) so far, held in 2010 between [Kenya, Uganda, and Scotland](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/series/440098.html), and the hosts Kenya were the victors.

Comment: Its quite interesting to hear.. Why have they stopped conducting tri-series Test tournaments??